# Cannot create DateTime column using Year, Month, Day, Hour and Minute columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to create a new column called DateTime using numerical columns "Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute".

```
Year    Month     Day     Hour     Minute
2019    5         9       11       0
2019    5         9       11       10
2019    5         9       11       20
```

This is my code:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute"]])
```

The expected result is:

```
DateTime
2019-05-09 11:00:00
2019-05-09 11:10:00
2019-05-09 11:20:00
```

However, I get this wrong result:

```
DateTime
2019-05-09
2019-05-09
2019-05-09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
d = {
    'Year': [2019,2019],
    'Month': [5,6],
    'Day': [12,13],
    'Hour': [12,20],
    'Minute': [30,45],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute"]]).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

df
```

```
    Year    Month   Day Hour    Minute  DateTime
0   2019       5    12  12        30    12/05/19 12:30
1   2019       6    13  20        45    13/06/19 20:45
```

Comment: In my dataframe, the year, month, day, hour and minute are integers, while your dataframe contain strings. Is it the reason why I get wrong result (only date)?

Comment: @Fluxy i edit answer you can see this is not for integer or string

Comment: For some reason it does not work for me. It's the same code as I showed in the question. Do you have any suggestion why it does not work for me?

Comment: @Fluxy I edit answer check this helps your or not?

Comment: yes, now it works. Could you please explain why it did not work in the classical way? Does it depend on pandas version?

Comment: @Fluxy I don't know exactly but in this way we specific exactly type of return, maybe some of the other programs you change the format and in this line, you specify what return type exactly